# richface resizable columns

Tags: java, richfaces

I'm just trying to modify some of our tables, especially in the way that the columns can be made bigger or smaller by dragging them with the mouse. Unfortunately I don't get it done and my google search didn't help me either.

The code looks like this:

```
<f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left" width="auto">
                            <c:if test="#{includeDefaultActionColumn}">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{messages['de.segal.baoss.module.numberrange.entity.NumberRangeName.ImpersonalNumber']}" />
                            </c:if>
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.bookingType']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{messages['de.segal.baoss.documents']}" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.transactionDate']}" />
                        </rich:column>
            <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.accountingExportDate']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.booking.generic.bookedBy']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.internalRecordNumber']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.transactionDetail.amount']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.externalRecordNumber']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <c:if test="#{_showStatus}">
                            <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{messages['invoicing.accountingTransaction.accountingTransactionStatus']}" />
                            </rich:column>
                        </c:if>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText value="#{messages['de.segal.baoss.module.article.entity.ConversionRate']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                        <rich:column styleClass="w-column-align-left">
                            <h:outputText value="#{messages['de.segal.baoss.module.article.entity.ConversionRate.date']}" />
                        </rich:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
```

Thanks for the help,
Pascal

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you using extendedDataTable? Normal datatables are not resizable.

Comment: Ya that was the problem :D thanks I could fix it

Answer (score 0):

A table in Richfaces whose columns have the ability to change dimensions is defined by the tag rich:extendedDataTable.

A working example you can find [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable)